How to launch 2 requests in python in parallel
I want to execute 2 functions in Python that execute requests under the hood. I don't mind to wait until the two have finished, but they should be executed in parallel.
I tried to use the concurrent.futures library, but that requires me to use an async and so on until the function on top of all, which is synchronous and would need a huge refactoring to make it async.
I'm trying with this approach, but I'm not sure if this actually parallelises everything correctly
def worker(function, queue_prepared, *args):
    result = function(*args)
    queue_prepared.put(result)

def launch_threads(param1, param2):
    queue_first = queue.Queue()
    queue_second = queue.Queue()
    thread_first = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(request1, queue_first, param1, param2))
    thread_second = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(request2, queue_second, param1))
    thread_first.start()
    thread_second.start()
    thread_first.join()
    thread_second.join()
    return queue_first, queue_second


queue_first, queue_second = launch_threads(param1,param2)

queue_first_finished = False
queue_second_finished = False

while not queue_first_finished or not queue_second_finished:
    if not queue_first_finished:
       if not queue_first.empty():
            first = queue_first.get(timeout=1)
       else:
             queue_first_finished = True
     if not queue_second_finished:
       if not queue_second.empty():
            first = queue_second.get(timeout=1)
       else:
             queue_second_finished = True

    


"launch_threads" seems like a misleading name because that function doesn't merely launch the threads, it also waits for them to finish. A better name might be  something like,  "do_work_in_parallel."

P.S., Do you know about the Python GIL? And, do you know how to disable it?

@SolomonSlow disabling the GIL makes python code 5-10% slower, also requests implies IO which is not affected by the GIL to begin with, there is a reason why this is not deployed by default, also you cannot use external packages without the gil as it is still unsafe, right now it is only experimental

@AhmedAEK, Python code is incapable of parallel processing unless the GIL is disabled. OP specifically says, "in parallel," and they provided an example with two threads. My comment assumes that they know what "parallel" means and, that their target box has at least two CPUs. "10% slower" times 2 equals 80% faster (for certain definitions of "faster" and "slower," and assuming that the algorithm can be perfectly parallelized.)

@SolomonSlow The GIL is responsible to keep the interpreter structure safe. So disabling it so far resulted in random crashes. Is this new version safe? I guess users can still write bad code causing race conditions but I am wondering about the interpreter structure which was not thread-safe without the GIL so far.

@JérômeRichard it is safe, now every PyObject has a lock that is locked before any action is done, even stack references have locks, this made python 5-10% slower (see the PEP) and if you load any C extension the GIL gets turned back ON until the library marks itself as safe without the gil, (you can still force it OFF but you might run into crashes) it is still very experimental at the moment.

you don't need to reinvent your own threadpool with queues, instead use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor and concurrent.futures.as_completed to get task results as soon as they complete, you can also add a timeout if needed.
import concurrent.futures
import time

def task(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(2)

wait_times = [2,1]
tasks = [pool.submit(task,i) for i in wait_times]

for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
    print(future.result())

1
2

note the timeout part is tricky because it doesn't actually terminate the task, it only stops the loop, and destroying the threadpool joins the pool, which means you will still wait for the task to complete.
Also you might want to store this threadpool globally and reuse it in many places, because creating threads is not cheap (typically 10s-100s of microseconds) whereas creating tasks is cheap (in the order of a few microseconds)
